# How to mute TestNG Reporter output when a test case passes

Tags: selenium, testng

I have a selenium test suite using TestNG and Reporter to log results on Jenkins.  I use Reporter in all methods to log activity to the console, and this in turn appears for each test listed in the Reporter html output on Jenkins.  What I'd like to do, is to only see the Reporter log output in the reports for the tests that fail.  If a test passes, I'd like to see just the test case name in the report with no logging.

I thought I could do this in my TestNGWatcher class where I override the onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) method and added the following line:

```
Reporter.clear();
```

That single line did what I wanted for the passing tests, but also disables Reporter output for the failed tests.  It seems to have turned of Reporter output entirely.

Is there a way to 'turn it on' when a test fails and turn it off when a test passes?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: I see in the Reporter.class that clear() erases the content of 'all the output generated so far', which I think explains why the one line is nuking everything and not just the output for a given test.  I'm probably going about this the wrong way.  Advice is welcome.

Comment: Another solution for my problem would be a way to make each entry in the html report accordion fold or something like that, so that I could expand the ones I want to see in full.

Comment: Can you please share that code in which its not working? Create a simple test and simple listener, It works as expected.

Comment: Before I post any code, can you clarify 'as expected'?  I'm hoping to turn Reporter output off or on for a single test when running a test suite.  I didn't make that clear in the original post, but I basically have a suite of 70+ tests running and only want to see Reporter.log output for tests that fail, and no logging at all when tests pass.  Thanks for responding!